# data folder on my Rails application ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my rails application I found folder called 'data' , I didn't create it manually , any clue what it's supposed to be ? and can I remove it ?

```
~/code/my_project$ ls 
Gemfile     README      TODO        config/     data/       lib/    public/     test/       vendor/ Gemfile.lock    Procfile    Rakefile    app/        config.ru   db/     log/        script/     tmp/

~/code/my_project/data$ ls
mysql/          performance_schema/ test/

~/code/my_project/data/mysql$ ls
columns_priv.MYD        help_category.MYD       ndb_binlog_index.MYD        servers.MYD         time_zone_name.MYD
columns_priv.MYI        help_category.MYI       ndb_binlog_index.MYI        servers.MYI         time_zone_name.MYI
columns_priv.frm        help_category.frm       ndb_binlog_index.frm        servers.frm         time_zone_name.frm
db.MYD              help_keyword.MYD        plugin.MYD          slow_log.CSM            time_zone_transition.MYD
db.MYI              help_keyword.MYI        plugin.MYI          slow_log.CSV            time_zone_transition.MYI
db.frm              help_keyword.frm        plugin.frm          slow_log.frm            time_zone_transition.frm
event.MYD           help_relation.MYD       proc.MYD            tables_priv.MYD         time_zone_transition_type.MYD
event.MYI           help_relation.MYI       proc.MYI            tables_priv.MYI         time_zone_transition_type.MYI
event.frm           help_relation.frm       proc.frm            tables_priv.frm         time_zone_transition_type.frm
func.MYD            help_topic.MYD          procs_priv.MYD          time_zone.MYD           user.MYD
func.MYI            help_topic.MYI          procs_priv.MYI          time_zone.MYI           user.MYI
func.frm            help_topic.frm          procs_priv.frm          time_zone.frm           user.frm
general_log.CSM         host.MYD            proxies_priv.MYD        time_zone_leap_second.MYD
general_log.CSV         host.MYI            proxies_priv.MYI        time_zone_leap_second.MYI
general_log.frm         host.frm            proxies_priv.frm        time_zone_leap_second.frm
```

Any clue what does it mean ? and weather if I can remove it or not .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation:

"Each MyISAM table is stored on disk in three files. The files have names that begin with the table name and have an extension to indicate the file type. An .frm file stores the table format. The data file has an .MYD (MYData) extension. The index file has an .MYI (MYIndex) extension."

This is your database, or at least a backup of it. I wouldn't delete it until you have found out where your MySQL engine is storing the database. You can probably find that out through one of the various db management tools that work with MySQL.

You might already know this, but if not, it's probably a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Those are files mysql uses to store data

- MYI = mysql index file
- MYD = mysql data file
- FRM = format (schema) file

You probably want to keep them.

Here's a list of [default locations for mysql data files](http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Where_are_MySQL%27s_Files?) on various platforms. Find your [`my.cnf`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) file on your system, which will tell you where mysql expects its data to be.

If after reading (or creating) the `my.cnf` file you find know the data directory is set to another location, then you will be able to safely delete this folder if you wish as these will be backup files.